# In DC the New 52 are Adam One and Merlin the same person?

Tags: dc, the-new-52, merlin

In issue number 2 of Stormwatch we learn that at the creation of the universe a powerful being named Adam One with the form of a very old white human male who is apparently British was created and that he would age backwards. In the 21st century Adam One looks like he's in his 20s or 30s.

In Demon Knights issues number 4 and 8 we learn that Merlin from King Arthur's Camelot is billions of years old and that he is aging backwards and that although he is still an old man he is younger than Adam One was at his birth at the creation of the universe.

If Adam One was about 90 years old at the beginning of the universe and several billion years later in the 21st century his reversed aging process makes him look 30 then he would have also looked 30 several hundred years ago in the time of King Arthur, but it's also possible the rate at which he ages is not constant and that sometimes he might grow younger faster!

So... is it possible that Merlin and Adam One are the same person?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! In Demon Knights issue 15 Merlin has been killed and is restored to life on the island of Avalon then he brows much younger and reveals his name to be "Adam" so that basically confirms it!

[image]